# because you can't populate a map with lists of lists

Tags: apex, map, list, sosl

trying to populate a map with a list list like this:

```
map<integer , listlist<<sobject>>> mpsosl=[find ' ba' IN all Fields RETURNING contact(name)];
```

> error:Illegal assignment from List<List> to Map<Integer,List<List>>

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your syntax is the issue from what you've shared. Nested collections like a List of Lists are possible within Apex, but it would be defined like this: `List<List<Contact>>` or even something like `List<List<Set<Integer>>>`.

Your [SOSL query will return a `List<List<SObject>>`](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_sosl). I would recommend assigning your results to a `List<List<SObject>>`, and then `put` it into your map.

```java
List<List<SObject>> mpsosl = [
    FIND ' ba' 
    IN All Fields 
    RETURNING Contact(name)
];
Map<Integer, List<List<SObject>> numToListOfList = new Map<Integer, List<List<SObject>>();
numToListOfList.put(1, mpsosl);
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of a SOSL is a List of List of SObjects. So, you should use -

```
List<List< SOject >> mpsosl=[find ' ba' IN all Fields RETURNING contact(name)];
```

Because of this you are getting the illegal assignment error.